# Xamarin Studio - Xamarin.Android missing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

i just downloaded Xamarin Studio, because Xamarin in visual studio was slow and the designer wasn't working.
When i try to create new project, the "Next" button is disabled. I googled that my Xamarin.Android is missing and my question is: How can i download and install it?

Comment: https://www.xamarin.com/faq#xpq6

Comment: So it's not possible to develop in Xamarin Studio anymore?

Comment: Although it's possible, it is not recommended. On Windows, you should be using Visual Studio as per the note above. On Mac, you should be using Visual Studio For Mac.

Comment: I can't use visual studio, so xamarin studio is my only option. How can i do it?

Comment: Why cant you use visual studio community?

Comment: As i said, it's too slow. It stops respoding every time i do something, emulating doesn't work, designer doesn't work, loading forever.